# 2 different post layouts in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just created thus BEAUTIFUL loop

```
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 <div class="row sectionrow" onclick="void(0)">
 <div class="col-sm-4 sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field(background_image_title); ?>');">
  <div class="textsmall" >
 <?php the_field(titlebreak); ?>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field(background_image_detail); ?>');">
     <div class="textbigrecipes">  
        <div class="inner">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">READ MORE</button></a>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

But I would like to invert the positon of the bootstrap divs on the second post and return to orginal on the third and ....

```
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <div class="row sectionrow" onclick="void(0)">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <div class="sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field(background_image_detail); ?>');">
     <div class="textbigrecipes">  
        <div class="inner">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
       <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">READ MORE</button></a>
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 sectionrecipes" style="background-image:url('<?php echo the_field(background_image_title); ?>');">
  <div class="textsmall" >
 <?php the_field(titlebreak); ?>
    </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. First declare a variable Outside the loop (like as $i =1),
```

2. Then check the condition.
       Mode of i

   ```
   example: 
   if($i% 2 == 0) {

   -----layout First code-----

   }else
   {

   -----layout Second code-----
   }
   ```
3. Increment the variable value ($i++)

Comment: I dont understand much of php, no sure where is the right place to put them but I think in this case only the second post will have a different valeu. My idea is first post layout 1, second post layout 2, third post layout 1, forth post layout 2 .........

Comment: 1. variable deceleration above the query post, 2. Then a condition checked after the query (that variable dividable by 2), 3. increment the variable

Comment: I hope it doesnt loop so messy.

Comment: can you take post id? or add custom field for post and check this condition $i% 2 == 0

Comment: I couldnt post all the code here, so I pu in codepen  http://codepen.io/LeandroAndrade/pen/ZpRjLY

Comment: and they are displaying on this page: http://cooleswan.juvoclients.com/category/recipes/    but I would like that every even post inverted to look like that http://cooleswan.juvoclients.com/recipes/ (this is a static page)